# Is there a way to print two/multiple variables in a single print statement without putting them into a string?

Tags: swift, xcode

My main goal is to sort a dictionary: e.g. [2: 4, 1: 2, 4: 8, 3: 6] by its keys, going from 1 to 4. So like [1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8]

I can print the pairs as items in an array, but then they're in string, so when the keys get into the double digits it won't sort them right in an ascending order. That's why i feel like if I could print them both in the same statement without putting them in a string it would work. But if there's a simpler way I'll take that also.

```
var dict=[2: 4, 1: 2, 4: 8, 3: 6]

var array=[String]()

for (key, value) in dict
{
     array.append("\(key):\(value)")
}
array.sort()

print(array)
```

The output would be:

> ["1:2", "2:4", "3:6", "4:8"]

Which works for this one but as soon as the keys get into double digits, it starts saying things like 10 comes before 2.

Comment: 1. Dictionaries have no order. 2. Show your code.

Comment: I know they have no order. I'm trying to take them out of the dictionary and sort them.

Answer (score 0):

I get **`["1:2", "2:4", "3:6", "4:8"]`**, not **`[1:2, 2:4, 3:6, 4:8]`**.

So, if that is exactly what you want, you have no need to convert key-value pairs to String before sorting.

```
var dict=[2: 4, 1: 2, 4: 8, 3: 6]

let array = dict.sorted{$0.key < $1.key}.map{"\($0.key):\($0.value)"}

print(array)
```

If you want something else, please clarify what you want.

Comment: @JoeyPeluka, that might not be, so I wrote _If you want something else, please clarify what you want_. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm saying there's nothing else to clarify. That's what I needed.

Comment: @JoeyPeluka, maybe I was mistaking the `No` in your first comment. If you can get what you were looking for, I'm very happy.